# How to create a different UI in Interface Builder in Xcode for each version of the iPhone without using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, ios11

I am trying to create a different layout for each version of the iPhone from version iPhone 5 to iPhone X, in the same orientation mode (Portrait). I don't want to use Auto Layout. Each time I have tried to move an element when designing for one model of the iPhone (iPhone SE), it affects another model (iPhone X). How do I dissasociate say an iPhone SE's User Interface layout from an iPhone X's User Interface layout?

Comment: First, why would you want to do that? If you really, ***really*** want to give yourself that type of headache, you'll probably need to create a separate Storyboard (or XIB) for each version.

Comment: No probably about it; you will need to create separate storyboards and then load the appropriate storyboard in your AppDelegate.  The other option is create your UI programatically rather than using a storyboard/xib.

Comment: I am just tired of going through growing pains with auto layout. I typically create my UI programmatically anyway, but this portion was previously created using storyboard. I just wanted to see if there was a way to get around using auto layout. Theoretically if I did choose to create a storyboard for each model, where would you pair the model with a particular storyboard? Or you would have to do this in code? (which is not a problem)

Comment: Pairing is definitely in the code. Storyboard Interface builder is there for a reason.